# NotImplementedException in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Before anything else: n00b warning!

I'm trying to write something to the local storage (at least I think I am), but I'm getting a `NotImplementedException`.

I **am using WP 8.1 preview** build (8.10.12359.845), but this seems like too basic a thing to be *Not Implemented*.

I must be doing something wrong, but the code is more or less what the *MSDN* tutorial said!

Here's the code:

```
class AccountStore
    {
        private const string ContainerAccountInfo = @"account";
        private const string KeyLastUpdated = "last_updated";
        private const string KeyUserId = "user_id";
        private const string KeyUsername = "user_name";
        private const string KeyEmail = "email";
        private const string KeyFullName = "full_name";
        private const string KeyStatus = "account_status";

        private static readonly object LOCK = new object();

        private ApplicationDataContainer Settings
        {
            get
            {
                // BOOM goes the code right here: System.NotImplementedException 
                return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer(ContainerAccountInfo, ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
            }
        }

        public AccountInfo StoredAccountInfo {
            get {
                lock (LOCK)
                    {
                        var settings = Settings.Values;

                        if (settings.ContainsKey(KeyLastUpdated)) 
                        return new AccountInfo {
                            UserId = settings[KeyUserId] as string,
                            Username = settings[KeyUsername] as string,
                            Email = settings[KeyEmail] as string,
                            FullName = settings[KeyFullName] as string,
                            Status = AccountUtils.fromString(settings[KeyStatus] as string)
                        };

                        return AccountInfo.NULL;
                    }
            }

            set
            {
                lock (LOCK)
                {
                    var settings = Settings.Values;

                    settings[KeyLastUpdated] = DateTime.Now;
                    settings[KeyUserId] = value.UserId;
                    settings[KeyUsername] = value.Username;
                    settings[KeyEmail] = value.Email;
                    settings[KeyFullName] = value.FullName;
                    settings[KeyStatus] = value.Status.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`System.NotImplementedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467263
  Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_LocalSettings()
       at APPNS.Auth.detail.AccountStore.get_Settings()
       at APPNS.Auth.detail.AccountStore.get_StoredAccountInfo()
       at APPNS.Auth.AccountManager..ctor()
       at APPNS.Auth.AccountManager.get_Instance()
       at APPNS.Auth.AccountManager.get_Info()
       at APPNS.Auth.AccountManager.get_IsRegistered()
       at APPNS.MainPage.checkRegistration()
       at APPNS.MainPage.PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException:`

Any input is appreciated.
My last exposure to C# was about 5 years ago and I'm quite rusty. I also have no experience with Windows Phone (I'm an Android developer). So if I'm doing something outright stupid above, I'd like to know that too!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set your "Target Windows Phone OS Version" to be Windows Phone 8.1? You can access this by right clicking your project and choosing "Properties".

Comment: I don't have 8.1 in the drop down. I also want to keep it compatible with 8.0 and up. Switching to IsolatedStorage worked for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because `LocalSettings` wasn't added until Windows Phone 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx

(**Minimum supported phone** Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and Windows Runtime apps])

In order to use it, your build target must be WP8.1 or higher.